# How to get the underlying array of a slice in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Let's say I have the following array of ints of length 3:

`nums := [3]int{1,2,3}`

Then I grab the slice of just the first two items

`numSlice := nums[:2]`

Invoking `cap` on numSlice and nums yields 3 in both cases, and `len` yields 2 and 3 respectively.

If I then append to that slice (`numSlice = append(numSlice, 10)`), the underlying array (`nums`) is now `[1 2 10]`. `cap` remains at 3 for both, as the underlying array of the slice is the same, and len for the slice is now 3.

However, if I append to that slice again (`numSlice = append(numSlice, 20)`), the underlying array of the slice must change - we see this is the case when `cap` now has doubled for numSlice and len is now 4.

Sorry for the overwrought explanation, just walking myself through it, but can someone explain to me what happens under the hood to the underlying array and how to get the reference to the new array?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, if you haven't already, you should read [this official blog post about slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals). That should clear up everything.

Now to access the underlying array, you can use a combination of [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect) and [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe). In particular, [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader)  contains a `Data` field which contains a pointer to the underlying array of a slice.

Example adapted from the documentation of the `unsafe` package:

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
data := *(*[4]int)(unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `Data` might not point to the start of the backing array: just to the 0-th element of the slice. So, in the case `numSlice := nums[1:]` it would actually end up pointing to the second element of the Array. [Example](http://play.golang.org/p/8fCCz9d7rG)

Comment: As a perhaps stupid question, what would the performance be on this?

Comment: @Highstead Not a stupid question at all! Performance often suffers when we use reflection, but in this case it should be pretty good. If I understand https://go.godbolt.org/z/h6v67McWr correctly, the compiler actually generates *less* code from the reflect/unsafe code here than from the much shorter code possible since 1.17, because the reflect/unsafe code doesn't have error checks.

Comment: ...and of course, "the reflect/unsafe code doesn't have error checks" means "don't use it". Just in case that was unclear. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Just as a headsup, answering your second question. Starting from [Go 1.17](https://golang.org/doc/go1.17), you can do it like this

```
(*[2]int)(numSlice)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F_Cahx1e352)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    nums := [3]int{1, 2, 3}
    numSlice := nums[:2]
    underArr1 := (*[2]int)(numSlice)
    fmt.Println(&underArr1[0]) //0xc000016018

    numSlice = append(numSlice, 10)
    underArr2 := (*[3]int)(numSlice)
    fmt.Println(&underArr2[0]) //0xc000016018 - same
    fmt.Println(nums) // [1 2 10]

    numSlice = append(numSlice, 20)
    underArr3 := (*[3]int)(numSlice)
    fmt.Println(&underArr3[0]) //0xc000078030 - different
    fmt.Println(cap(numSlice)) // 6
}
```

To be honest, you don't have to convert to array pointer to see the adresses, I just do it to answer your second question.

The behaviour is indeed the way you described it. When you append `10`, you still have one field left in your underlying array (because its length is 3, but your numSlice is 2), and even though it is currently occupied by a `3`, it can be used, and `3` is overwritten by `10`.

When you append a `20`, there are no fields left, so it creates a new underlying array (most likely 6 fields long, twice as big) and copies all the data from the original array there and moves the pointer to that array.