# nil slices vs non-nil slices vs empty slices in Go language

Tags: go, null, slice

I am a newbie to Go programming. I have read in go programming book that slice consists of three things: a pointer to an array, length and capacity.

I am getting confused between:

- nil slices (slice has no underlying array to point to, len = 0, cap=0)
- non-nil slices where only len = 0, cap = 0
- empty slices.

Can anyone please tell whether nil and empty slices are same things?
If they both are different, then please tell what is the difference between those two? How to test whether a slice is empty or not? Also, what value does the pointer holds in non-nil slices, whose length and capacity are zero?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

### Observable behavior

`nil` and empty slices (with 0 capacity) are not the same, but their observable behavior is the same (almost all the time). By this I mean:

- You can pass them to the builtin [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) and [`cap()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#cap) functions
- You can `for range` over them (will be 0 iterations)
- You can slice them (by not violating the restrictions outlined at [Spec: Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions); so the result will also be an empty slice)
- Since their length is 0, you can't change their content (appending a value creates a new slice value)

See this simple example (a `nil` slice and 2 non-`nil` empty slices):

```
var s1 []int         // nil slice
s2 := []int{}        // non-nil, empty slice
s3 := make([]int, 0) // non-nil, empty slice

fmt.Println("s1", len(s1), cap(s1), s1 == nil, s1[:], s1[:] == nil)
fmt.Println("s2", len(s2), cap(s2), s2 == nil, s2[:], s2[:] == nil)
fmt.Println("s3", len(s3), cap(s3), s3 == nil, s3[:], s3[:] == nil)

for range s1 {}
for range s2 {}
for range s3 {}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_EjBzoz0Ed)):

```
s1 0 0 true [] true
s2 0 0 false [] false
s3 0 0 false [] false
```

(Note that slicing a `nil` slice results in a `nil` slice, slicing a non-`nil` slice results in a non-`nil` slice.)

Besides an exception, you can only tell the difference by comparing the slice value to the predeclared identifier `nil`, they behave the same in every other aspect. **Do note however that many packages do compare slices to `nil` and may act differently based on that (e.g. [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) and [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) packages).**

The only difference is by [converting the slice to an array pointer](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_from_slice_to_array_pointer) (which was added to the language in [Go 1.17](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17)). Converting a non-`nil` slice to an array pointer will result in a non-`nil` pointer, converting a `nil` slice to an array pointer will result in a `nil` pointer.

To tell if a slice is empty, simply compare its length to `0`: `len(s) == 0`. It doesn't matter if it's the `nil` slice or a non-`nil` slice, it also doesn't matter if it has a positive capacity; if it has no elements, it's empty.

```
s := make([]int, 0, 100)
fmt.Println("Empty:", len(s) == 0, ", but capacity:", cap(s))
```

Prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T29nh9hVpd)):

```
Empty: true , but capacity: 100
```

### Under the hood

A slice value is represented by a struct defined in [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader):

```
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}
```

In case of a `nil` slice, this struct will have its zero value which is all its fields will be their zero value, that is: `0`.

Having a non-`nil` slice with both capacity and length equal to `0`, `Len` and `Cap` fields will most certainly be `0`, but the `Data` pointer may not be. It *will* not be, that is what differentiates it from the `nil` slice. It will point to a zero-sized underlying array.

Note that the Go spec allows for values of different types having 0 size to have the same memory address. [Spec: System considerations: Size and alignment guarantees:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees)

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. **Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.**

Let's check this. For this we call the help of the [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package, and "obtain" the `reflect.SliceHeader` struct "view" of our slice values:

```
var s1 []int
s2 := []int{}
s3 := make([]int, 0)

fmt.Printf("s1 (addr: %p): %+8v\n",
    &s1, *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s1)))
fmt.Printf("s2 (addr: %p): %+8v\n",
    &s2, *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s2)))
fmt.Printf("s3 (addr: %p): %+8v\n",
    &s3, *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s3)))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/49I_2os91G)):

```
s1 (addr: 0x1040a130): {Data:       0 Len:       0 Cap:       0}
s2 (addr: 0x1040a140): {Data: 1535812 Len:       0 Cap:       0}
s3 (addr: 0x1040a150): {Data: 1535812 Len:       0 Cap:       0}
```

What do we see?

- All slices (slice headers) have different memory addresses
- The `nil` slice has `0` data pointer
- `s2` and `s3` slices do have the same data pointer, sharing / pointing to the same 0-sized memory value

Comment: Can you please explain a bit about what exactly is 0-sized memory value? I mean is it like, for empty slices, there is underlying array having memory allocated but no elements are there OR is it like there is no memory allocated underneath and the data pointer in the slice structure holds any random address?

Comment: @SurbhiVyas The memory address doesn't have any meaning in a sense that where it points to contains no data, or rather the pointed area is not to be read because only 0 bytes is reserved for it (that is: nothing). It is a special, reserved address for variables of different types having 0 size. It's an implementation detail, you should not worry about it or make anything of it.

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation.

Comment: the important thing to notice here, go's `append` function will not panic if provided a slice of nil value. Semantically, it treats such an input as an _empty_ slice and append to it as such. This avoids a lot of boiler-plate nil checks in user code.

Comment: *"they behave the same in every other aspect"* - that's not quite correct. For example, `json.Marshal(s)` returns `"null"` if `s` is `nil`, but `"[]"` if `s` is empty (but not `nil`). I guess there are other cases where `nil` and empty slices behave differently.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica You quoted only half of the sentence. The full sentence is: _"You can only tell the difference by comparing the slice value to the predeclared identifier `nil`, they behave the same in every other aspect."_ And that's exactly what the `encoding/json` package does: it compares it to `nil`.

Comment: @icza Yes, I'm being a bit picky, but... if someone told me "you can only tell the difference by comparing the slice value to nil, they behave the same in every other aspect", and then I found out that they behave differently when I pass them to `json.Marshal()`, I'd say "you were wrong, I didn't compare them to nil, and yet they didn't behave the same way". (Why and how `Marshal()` does that is an implementation detail.) The correct wording would be "behave the same in most other aspects" or something like this; "behave the same in every other aspect" is misleading.

Comment: Here's another aspect in which nil and empty slices don't behave the same: `var n []int = nil; e := []int{}; np := (*[0]int)(n); ep := (*[0]int)(e); fmt.Println(np, ep)` I'm pretty sure no slice gets compared to nil when you run this code. :-)

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica What you have there are not slices but **pointers to arrays**, that's a completely different thing (slices and arrays are not the same). Not to mention zero-sized types are a completely different topic (as they may be placed to the same memory location according to the spec, and `[0]int` has zero size). Also, the `fmt` package does a lot of "magic" under the hood, just like the `encoding/json` package. It's like you write an `f()` function that takes a slice, and inside it you compare the slice to `nil` and do different stuff based on that...

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica Nevertheless, I added a note in bold to bring this to attention.

Comment: @icza I know all that. My example happens to deal with pointers to the underlying arrays, but that's not really the point. The example creates two slices (one nil, one empty) and demonstrates that they behave differently, although there's no comparison of a slice to nil anywhere. The point is: nil and empty slices can behave differently in several ways, even if you don't compare them to nil. The added note is good, but it doesn't cover this case (and possibly many other cases where nil and empty slices behave differently, even without any comparison to nil).

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica OK, I got your point. Do note however that conversion from slice to array pointer was only added in Go 1.17, before that it was not allowed. Edited the answer.

Comment: @icza Thanks for humoring my pickiness. :-) By the way, getting the array pointer was possible before 1.17, but the syntax was a lot more cumbersome. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706843/how-to-get-the-underlying-array-of-a-slice-in-go

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica Yes, using package `unsafe`, but let's not reason about that solution as package `unsafe` steps around the type safety of Go programs. It's not an everyday tool for a Go programmer (but rather a last resort).

Answer (score 3):

```
var s1 []int         // nil slice
s2 := []int{}        // non-nil, empty slice
s3 := make([]int, 0) // non-nil, empty slice
```

warning, if dealing with JSON, a nil slice will encode to null instead of [], which can break some (javascript) clients that try to iterate (without a null check) over null which isn't iterable.

Answer (score 2):

A slice can be nil in a very literal sense:

```
var n []int
n == nil // true
```

That is the only easy case. The notion of "empty" slice is not well defined: A slice `s` with `len(s) == 0` is certainly empty, regardless of its capacity.
The most sensible thing to do is: Ignore the underlying implementation, one never needs to know how a slice is represented internally. All it matters is the defined behaviour of a slice.

> How to test whether a slice is empty or not?

The most sensible definition of " slice `s` is empty" is a slice containing no elements which translates to `len(s) == 0`. This definition holds for nil as well as for non-nil slices.

> Can anyone please tell whether nil and empty slices are same things? If they both are different, then please tell what is the difference between those two?

Technically a nil slice and a non-nil slice are different (one being == nil, the other being != nil), but this distinction typically does not matter as you can `append` to a nil slice and len and cap on nil slices return 0

```
var n []int
len(n) == cap(n) == 0 // true
n = append(n, 123)
len(n) == 1 // true
```

Read about zero values in Go for further information. A nil slice is like a nil channel or a nil map: It is uninitialised. You initialise by either `make`ing them or by a literal. As said above, there is no reason to think about the underlying representation.

> Also, what value does the pointer holds in non-nil slices, whose length and capacity are zero?

This is an implementation detail which may vary from compiler to compiler or even from version to version. Nobody needs to know this to write correct and portable Go programs.

Comment: To the last question, per [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), "A slice created with make always allocates a new, hidden array to which the returned slice value refers."