# Convert nil []byte variable to string doesn't panic. Why not?

Tags: go

```
package main

import ("fmt")

func main() {

    var bts []byte =nil
    fmt.Println("the result :", string(bts)) // why not panic ?
    // the result :
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dzRzzKvUyd

Comment: Related: [nil slices vs non-nil slices vs empty slices in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305170/nil-slices-vs-non-nil-slices-vs-empty-slices-in-go-language/44305910#44305910).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for any type that can be `nil` you can generate whatever string representation you like! It's because when implementing `fmt.Stringer` interface (see [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)) - or any function on a type that can be `nil` - you can have a `nil` for receiver value. In other words you can call methods on `nil` objects in contrast with OOP languages. In [this](https://play.golang.org/p/XMGSiJJLtx) sample code, you'll see `ʕ◔ϖ◔ʔ hey nilo!` for a `nil` value of the second type, but `BOO DATA!!! :: Hi! :)` when you have an element inside (it prints just the first element as a sample code).

And again keep in mind `nil` [is typed](https://www.gmarik.info/blog/2016/understanding-golang-nil-value/) in go.

Answer (score 2):

Because zero value of a slice (`nil`) acts like a zero-length slice. E.g. you also can declare a slice variable and then append to it in a loop:

```
// Filter returns a new slice holding only
// the elements of s that satisfy f()
func Filter(s []int, fn func(int) bool) []int {
    var p []int // == nil
    for _, v := range s {
        if fn(v) {
            p = append(p, v)
        }
    }
    return p
}
```

More details can be found here: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: You can even slice a nil slice, which is really weird: `fmt.Printf("wat: %v\n", ([]byte(nil))[0:0])` does not panic.