# Can I recover elements that I sliced off the beginning of a slice?

Tags: go

```
a := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6}
b := a[1:len(a)-1]
fmt.Println(b) // -> [2 3 4 5]
```

I can get the `6` back from `b`:

```
c := b[:len(b)+1]
fmt.Println(c) // -> [2 3 4 5 6]
```

But can I get the `1` back?

If I try

```
c := b[-1:]
```

I get

> invalid slice index -1 (index must be non-negative)

If I can't get it back, does it mean it will be garbage collected?

Comment: In practice you just keep a reference to the original slice if you want the space from the original slice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be garbage collected:[Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

If you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706843/how-to-get-the-underlying-array-of-a-slice-in-go) it shows you how to use reflection to get the underlying array, from which 1 is recoverable using unsafe and reflect packages.

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
data := *(*[4]int)(unsafe.Pointer(hdr.Data))
```